# write and display correctly and in best practice javascript code in react

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, reactjs, syntax-error

In my react application I wrote this following code (filename SearchBox.jsx) :

```
import React from 'react'
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom'
import $ from 'jquery'

export default class SearchBox extends React.Component {
    createAjax() {
        let query = ReactDOM.findDOMNode(this.refs.query).value
        let category = ReactDOM.findDOMNode(this.refs.category).value
        let URL = `https://another.url.com/search?term=${query}&country=us&entity=${category}`
        this.props.search(URL)
        console.log(URL)
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div className="app__wrapper">
                <section className="map-container">
                    <iframe src="https://www.google.com/maps/embed?pb=!1m14!1m12!1m3!1d89077.13001931181!2d4.835120949999999!3d45.7579555!2m3!1f0!2f0!3f0!3m2!1i1024!2i768!4f13.1!5e0!3m2!1sfr!2sfr!4v1455092172025" width="100%" height="100%" frameBorder="0" style={{border:0}} allowFullScreen>
                    </iframe>
                </section>
                <section className="header">
                    <div className="header__logo">
                        <i className="fa fa-shopping-basket"></i>
                        <h1><b>my</b>Market</h1>
                    </div>
                </section>
                <section className="search">
                    <div className="search__wrapper">
                        <div className="search__bar">
                            <input type="text" className="search__input" placeholder="Recherche à proximité de ..."></input>
                            <button className="search__button search__button--close"><i className="fa fa-times"></i>
                            </button>
                        </div>
                        <ul className="search__list">
                            <li className="search__item search__item--prox"><i className="fa fa-dot-circle-o"></i>
                                Ma position actuelle
                            </li>
                            <li className="search__item">Lyon</li>
                            <li className="search__item">Chassieu</li>
                            <li className="search__item">Villeurbanne</li>
                            <li className="search__item">Mâcon</li>
                            <li className="search__item">vaux-en-velin</li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                </section>
                <script type="text/javascript">
                    console.log("blabla")
                </script>
            </div>
        )
    }
}
```

I am new to react.js, and I am not sure what happened. 
No errors occured in my browser console.

But if I would like to add some jQuery script Ilike this in the script tag:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('.search__input').on("focusin", function(){
            $('.search__button--close').fadeIn();
            $('.search__list').css('display', 'block');
        });
        $('.search__input').on("focusout", function(){
            $('.search__button--close').fadeOut();
            $('.search__list').css('display', 'none');
        });
        $('.days__item').on('click', function(){
            if($(this).attr('data-checked') == 'true'){
                $(this).attr('data-checked', 'false');
            } else {
                $(this).attr('data-checked', 'true');
            }
        })
    });
</script>
```

I have this following error in my browser console:

```
Module build failed: SyntaxError: /my/path/to/SearchBox.jsx: Unexpected token (62:26)
  60 |                             $('.search__button--close').fadeIn();
  61 |                             $('.search__list').css('display', 'block');
> 62 |                         });
     |                           ^
  63 |                         $('.search__input').on("focusout", function(){
  64 |                             $('.search__button--close').fadeOut();
  65 |                             $('.search__list').css('display', 'none');
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can attach to the same event handlers using React. For example your focusout event could become a blur (no descendant element handling, but that doesn't seem needed here):

```
<input type="text" onBlur={this.handleSearchInputBlur} className="search__input" placeholder="Recherche à proximité de ..."></input>
```

You can then set the state of your component, for example:

```
this.searchInputHasFocus = false;
```

Which then is used in your render to set, for example, a CSS fadeOut class and something that prevents the rendering of the search-list element. 
Generally in React it's disadvised to do much DOM manipulation. React is specifically designed to do this efficiently. If need be, I sometimes use it but in this case you can use the functionality of React to remove the search list etc. Rendering a script tag from a component should never really be necessary.

Recommended reading:

https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/thinking-in-react.html

https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/interactivity-and-dynamic-uis.html

Answer (score 1):

Instead of the `<script>` tag, you could put the `console.log` outside JSX:

```
render() {
        console.log("blabla")
        return (
            <div className="app__wrapper">...</div>
        )
}
```